# Python IDLE doesn't start after installing Immunity Debugger

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

I currently switched from `olldbg` to `ImmunityDebugger` and realized that my *IDLE* didn't start any longer. Immunity Debugger installs itself a copy of Python (the newest one: 2.7), so I thought it wouldn't change anything important, since i had alerady 2.7 installed.

If I want to start IDLE manually (`cmd -> "python.exe -m idlelib.idle"`) Mr. Cmd tells me following:

> IDLE can't import Tkinter.  Your Python may not be configured for Tk.

Then I ran python in the console and wanted to import Tkinter manually:

```
>>> import Tkinter
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
> File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 38, in  <module>
> import FixTk   
> File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\FixTk.py", line 65, in <module>
> import _tkinter
> ```
>
> **ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 not a valid win32 application**

Any Ideas what could be misconfigured?
(Im using windows 7 64 Bit Home Edition)
Nikolai

Comment: Is `_tkinter.pyd` in Python27\DLLs? tcl85.dll, tk85.dll? Is there a Python27\tcl directory?

Comment: Much appreciate your Help. everthing were it should be. (all your suggestions are positive - no dll or Directory is missing). The tcl directory seems 'full' too: http://oi43.tinypic.com/2vir0j5.jpg and http://oi43.tinypic.com/v7grya.jpg

Comment: Is C:\Python27\DLLs in your `sys.path`?

Comment: Yeah, actually it is:
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\
\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27
', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: Try `import _tkinter`. If that fails, try: `import os, ctypes; os.chdir(r'C:\Python27\DLLs')`. Then try to load the DLLs: `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('tcl85.dll')` and also `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('tk85.dll')`.

Comment: everything works fine untill I want to laod the dlls. (ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('tcl85.dll') and ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('tk85.dll')). The first time i just reinstalled Python which solved the problem. But then Immunity Debugger doesn't work anymore. its pretty strange. By the way: The error message is the same ("%1 is not a valid win32 app") as before...thx for your help

Comment: Which Python did you install, 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

The install probably messed up the pythonpath, try to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv),
than you install packages in it with [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip). It's always recommended.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Immunity Debugger set the TCL_LIBRARY and TK_LIBRARY environment variables.  See the first answer to [Idle won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509579/python-idle-won%C2%B4t-start?rq=1)