# IDLE (Python GUI) does not open up

Tags: python, python-3.3, python-idle

I have Python33 installed on a Windows 7 , 64 bits machine.
The IDLE used to work, but recently when I click on the icon nothing happens.
I have seen similar issues reported and have followed anyone that applies but could not resolve it. When I try to run `idle.py` on a DOS prompt I get this message:

```
C:\Windows\system32>c:\Python33\Lib\idlelib\idle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\idlelib\idle.py", line 11, in <module>
    idlelib.PyShell.main()
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1519, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1789, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, want
objects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    C:/Ruby193/lib/tcl8.5 C:/lib/tcl8.5 C:/lib/tcl8.5 C:/library C:/library C:/t
cl8.5.12/library C:/tcl8.5.12/library


This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

Any help to resolve this is really appreciated.

Comment: Going to take a random guess and say this means Tcl wasn't installed properly.

Comment: possible answer to this one - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10955437/2689986

Comment: @DanielRoseman if I reinstall Tcl does it effect my Python installation and all the packages I have installed? Where should I get the Tcl?

Answer (score 0):

The PSF installer from python.org should install _tkinter.pyd, tcl85.dll, tk85.dll in `C:/python33/DLLs`.  It you start the console interpreter and run `import sys; sys.path`, that directory should be on the path.  If the above are all true, some other installer may have set TCL_LIBRARY or TK_LIBRARY to some other directory.