# Python IDLE shell not opening

Tags: python, python-idle

I am using Windows 8.1 and have installed OpenCV for Python 2.7. I was able to complete the installation. But I have not been able to open the python IDLE shell. Whenever I click on it, It opens for a second and disappears.

I did try all the steps mentioned in this link [Python IDLE won´t start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509579/python-idle-won%C2%B4t-start?rq=1)

Also I could not find the environment variable called TCL_LIBRARY in my system.

Comment: I have python installed on Windows 8.1, both for 2.7 and 3.4, and everything works perfectly, out of the box. Try remove everything got to do with python and then reinstall python 2.7 on your system.

Comment: What is 'it' in 'click on it'?  How did you install Python 27?  Is that the only Python installed? Did you try IDLE before installing OpenCV?  In any case, try to start IDLE from Command Prompt with `python -m idlelib` so you potentially see an error message.  You should not see TCL_LIBRARY unless you add it, and it should not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

THIS WORKS:

I have installed Anaconda python,so

open python\Lib\idlelib

There you can find idle file of python

This will open python shell

Pin it to taskbar and work

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem with ActivePython 2.7 
It was resolved when I install x86 version of ActivePython (At first I tried x64)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly the problem was. It might have been various versions conflict or just that my installation was not right. I removed every previously installed versions and started from scratch, and it seems to be working fine for now.