# How can I resolve the issue of Python Idle not opening?

Tags: python

Good day everyone, I just bought a system with window 8. I downloaded Python 3.10 and after installing it,to my surprise, the Idle does not open when I click, although the command prompt is working. I've tried all possible best to resolve this, all to no avail. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How have you installed IDLE and what are you doing to open it?

Comment: I installed the python exe file successful. The Command prompt is working but the Idle is not

Answer (score 0):

With the given details, I can't say something that will work 100% but there are people who were dealing with similar issues:

```
I had this issue too, I realized that I had installed the 32bit version on a machine running 64bit. So I uninstalled and installed the 64bit and it's fine now.
```

or

```
Can you launch Python from a command line and then launch IDLE from there?

    cd c:\python33
    python

After python starts, enter the following:

    import idlelib.idle
```

I suggest you either try these methods or just straight up reinstall Python to your computer. But be sure to download the right one for your hardware.
Source:https://bugs.python.org/issue16365
Another place which you can visit as well:[Python IDLE shell not opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947291/python-idle-shell-not-opening)

Again, you need to provide more detail.

Comment: I tried to launch from the command line. It just goes off. Nothing open